# How show filter image out of feature in other color?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am using OpenLayers JS to filter the features display. I am trying to show the filtered imaged in other color keeping rest of feature also.

Following is the code I am using for filtering:

```
var a="73.84";
var b="73.89"
var filter= new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
     type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
   filters: [
    new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
       type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
         property: "x",
         lowerBoundary:a,
 upperBoundary:b
            }),
            new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                property: "y",
                lowerBoundary:"18.51",
                upperBoundary:"18.56"
            })]
    });

var parser = new OpenLayers.Format.Filter.v1_1_0();
var filterAsXml = parser.write(filter);
var xml = new OpenLayers.Format.XML();
var filterAsString = xml.write(filterAsXml);

allwards.params["FILTER"] = filterAsString;
allwards.redraw();
```

Using this code my feature is filtered but original feature are removed and only filtered feature are show. I want to show original features along with filtered feature in different color.

Please help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be (and I am just making a half educated guess based on something I've only just started playing with so bear with me) because you are using a filter rather than a styleMap. A styleMap should allow you to style features a particular way based on attributes.

A filter is designed to filter out things you don't want, but from what you are sying it seems that you want all the features but you want them to look different from each other, and for that I think you'd be better of setting the styleMap of the layer rather than the filter.

```
 styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    'default': new OpenLayers.Style ( //this is a default that will be applied to all
        {
            graphicHeight : 40,
            graphicWidth : 40,
            cursor : "pointer"
       },
       {
            rules: [
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                    property: "x",
                    lowerBoundary:a,
                    upperBoundary:b
                }),
                symbolizer: { //this is the bit that defines the style you want applied
                        externalGraphic : "icon1.png"
                    }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.BETWEEN,
                    property: "y",
                    lowerBoundary:"18.51",
                    upperBoundary:"18.56"
                }),
                symbolizer: {
                        externalGraphic : "icon2.png"
                    }
                }),
                new OpenLayers.Rule({ //this rule is for anything else
                    elseFilter: true,
                    symbolizer: {
                        externalGraphic : "icon3.png"
                    }
                })
            ]
        }
    )
})
```

This is a very basic guess and may have errors or may not be what you are after at all. But no one else has answered yet so it may be handy. You may also want to take a look at the OpenLayers documentation for [StyleMaps](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html#stylemap) and [Rules](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Rule-js.html)

Comment: thanks for replying will try and then will let you know if it worked.